# twitter-bootstrap nav not toggling collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my markup for my nav using bootstrap....
I'm not sure why the div with class of 'mynavbar' is not toggling open and close (by adding the 'in' class to it) when the button with a data-target='.mynavbar' is clicked (this is only on smaller screens where the hamburger type menu shows instead of the links "work, about, contact)

ALso, on large and small screens, should the li's that are clicked on have the class of "active" added to them?  I'm not seeing this happen either

```
    <nav class='navbar navbar-fixed-top drop-shadow'>
        <div class='container-fluid'>
            <div class='navbar-header page-scroll'>
                <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.mynavbar'>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                </button>
                <a class='navbar-brand page-scroll' href='#'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class='collapse navbar-collapse mynavbar'>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                    <li><a class='page-scroll' href='#work'>Work</a></li>
                    <li><a class='page-scroll' href='#about'>About</a></li>                 
                    <li><a class='page-scroll' href='#contact'>Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target to ID in `<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">`, instead of class. Then change the element that has `collapse navbar-collapse` class to `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">`

Overall, this code should work for you

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse drop-shadow" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a class="page-scroll" href="#work">Work</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And, you can add `class="active"` to your `<li>` when clicked, this is often handled in the server-side or in your own URL router